# alternative for typeof(object).TypeHandle.Value

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

i am porting a c# project to silverlight windows phone 7. Do you know what is the alternative for TypeHandle.Value for a Type class?

i can't find "Value" in the TypeHandle definition.

Here is an example from my code:

```
public override IEnumerable<MemberInfo> GetSerializableMembers(Type type)
{
    MemberInfo[] properties;
    if (!memberCache.TryGetValue(type.TypeHandle.Value, out properties))
        memberCache.Add(type.TypeHandle.Value, properties = base.GetSerializableMembers(type).ToArray());
    return properties;
}
```

It does not compile in WP7 at:

```
type.TypeHandle.Value
```

and same problem for : attributeType.TypeHandle.Value in this code:

```
T GetSingleAttributeOrDefault<T>(PropertyInfo propertyInfo) where T : Attribute, new()
{
    Type attributeType = typeof(T);
    Attribute attribute;
    var key = new PointerPair(propertyInfo.GetGetMethod().MethodHandle.Value, attributeType.TypeHandle.Value);
    if (!attributeCache.TryGetValue(key, out attribute))
        attributeCache.Add(key, attribute = base.GetSingleAttributeOrDefault<T>(propertyInfo));
    return attribute as T;
}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need the map to be based on the type handle anyway? Why not just have the key be a `Type`? Likewise for your attribute cache, just cache on the `MethodInfo` of the method and the `Type` of the attribute.

Comment: i did not write this code by myself. they ask me to compile it in wp7. but if there is no way to keep the same code, i will see if they permit me to make modifications.

Comment: hi Jon, could you please just write what you explained in some line of code? i tried to do the same way you explained to me but with no success.

Comment: Please edit what you've tried into your question and describe in what way it didn't work then. You just need a `Dictionary<Type, MemberInfo[]>` for the first piece of code, and `Dictionary<Tuple<Type, MethodInfo>, Attribute>` for the second.

Comment: @Jon Skeet  could you please clear the thing with base handle. I always cached with types, but recently find note in Jeffrey Richter book, what using runTimeTypeHandle a bit more efficently, at least holds less memory in heap. Now I am on my way to research this area.

Comment: @Roma: I've no idea what you mean by "clear the thing with base handle" - I suggest you ask a new and specific question.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Sorry, I mistyped) I meant RuntimeField/Type/MethodHandle 

 You answered to user3133279 - "Why do you need the map to be based on the type handle anyway? Why not just have the key be a Type?"

So my small answer is - does caching with runtimehandles instead of straight type/fieldinfo give us some real profit? Cause I have some reflection methods with huge data, it works pretty fast with caching, but I dont mind to improve perfomance.

Comment: @Roma: Well that's not so much an answer as another question. I don't know if any benefit to using the type handle... I can't see how the amount of data would affect it, but I suggest you get test it in your context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thank you Jon. 
i changed the key. now it compile.
 here is the new code:

```
 readonly Dictionary<Tuple<Type, MethodInfo>, Attribute> attributeCache = new Dictionary<Tuple<Type, MethodInfo>, Attribute>();

 T GetSingleAttributeOrDefault<T>(PropertyInfo propertyInfo) where T : Attribute, new()
    {            
        Type attributeType = typeof(T);
        Attribute attribute;

        //var key = new PointerPair(propertyInfo.GetGetMethod().MethodHandle.Value, attributeType.TypeHandle.Value);
        var key = new Tuple<Type, MethodInfo>(attributeType, propertyInfo.GetGetMethod());
        if (!attributeCache.TryGetValue(key, out attribute))
            attributeCache.Add(key, attribute = base.GetSingleAttributeOrDefault<T>(propertyInfo));
        return attribute as T;
    }
```